# Drill Deeper In Recursive Processing

Tags: applescript

I have a folder that is three levels deep, each level contains a good amount of files. I am able to get two levels deep with the script below, however the third level is posing a bit of a challenge. Would someone mind offering some guidance as to how I am supposed to get one level deeper? Use python or another language wouldn't be acceptable, as I am trying to see how this works with AppleScript.

```
set sourceFolder to (choose folder)

tell application "Finder"
    my changeFileNameCase(sourceFolder, "upper")
    repeat with subFolder in (get every folder of folder sourceFolder)
        my changeFileNameCase(subFolder as alias, "upper")

        #This Is No Good
        repeat with theFolder in (get every folder of folder subFolder)
            my changeFileNameCase(theFolder, "upper")
        end repeat

    end repeat
end tell

on changeFileNameCase(targetFolder, caseToSwitchTo)
    tell application "Finder"
        set fileList to every file of folder targetFolder
        repeat with theFile in fileList
            set oldName to name of theFile
            set newName to my changeCaseOfText(oldName, caseToSwitchTo)
            set the name of theFile to newName
        end repeat
    end tell
end changeFileNameCase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the handler recursive you have to get all items of the folder and check the class of each item.

- If the class is `folder` call the handler passing the folder
- If the class is `file` rename it

---

```
set sourceFolder to (choose folder)
changeFileNameCase(sourceFolder, "upper")

on changeFileNameCase(targetFolder, caseToSwitchTo)
    tell application "Finder"
        set theList to every item of targetFolder
        repeat with i from 1 to count theList
            set theItem to item i of theList
            if class of theItem is folder then
                my changeFileNameCase(theItem, caseToSwitchTo)
            else
                set oldName to name of theItem
                set newName to my changeCaseOfText(oldName, caseToSwitchTo)
                set name of theItem to newName
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end changeFileNameCase
```

Comment: Ah, I almost see where you're going with this, however it looks like if theItem is a folder, this would rename the folder, where as I am only looking to rename the files. Im assuming thats where I'd have to build a list of subFolders? If theItem is a folder - build a list of subfolders?

Comment: No, if the item is a folder it calls the handler recursively. The  number of levels doesn't matter.

Comment: Second look, I see the handler is calling itself. Anyhow its throwing out an error on calling itself error "Finder got an error: Can’t continue changeFileNameCase." number -1708 I'll spend some time picking this apart

Comment: My bad, there's a `my` missing. I updated the answer.

Comment: I just caught it myself, very interesting approach. I like it.